# How to run BQ command in crontab

Tags: cron, google-bigquery

I try to import CSV file to the Bigquery with a BQ command line and it will work without issue in bash script. When I try to run this script with crontab i have error message said "bq: command not found"

Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
bq load --field_delimiter=";" --source_format=CSV.....
```

This script working when I run from shell.

This is the cron job

```
* * * * * /users/user/desktop/test.sh
```

Why it isn't working on crontab ?

Comment: In your Terminal, run `which bq` then add the full path that you discover into your script. Remember your cron job didn't login interactively like you did, so its PATH is likely not set the same as your Terminal session.

Comment: I add "PATH=/Users/user/...../google-cloud-sdk/bin/bq" which is discovered by terminal but still same result "bq: command not found"

Comment: The PATH must describe the directory containing your programs, not the path to a single program. Remove the `/bq` at the end.

Comment: Its work ! Thank you very much !!

Comment: @MarkSetchell would you kindly post your last message as an answer? For future reference of the community.

Comment: @Mangu I think there are hundreds of similar crontab questions that fail because of the PATH. The problem is more that the community doesn't always look...

Answer (score 1):

Your `PATH` variable must describe the directory containing your programs, not the path to a single program.

In this case, it should be `../google-cloud-sdk/bin` and not `../google-cloud-sdk/bin/bq`.